# ConcurrencyCheck throws OptimisticConcurrencyException on first single update

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, entity-framework

I'm doing a simple update and it works if I won't modify the field that I decorated with `[ConcurrencyCheck]` attribute.

This is my property:

```
[Required]
[Index]
[Display(Name="First Name")]
[ConcurrencyCheck]
public string firstname { get; set; }
```

This is my update action method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Err()]
public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(Entries entry)
 {
     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
            CtxRepoRBMS<CarlCtx, Entries> ctxRDMS = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<CtxRepoRBMS<CarlCtx, Entries>>();
            MongoRepo<Items> ctxMongo = new MongoRepo<Items>(client: new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost"), dbName: "items");

            ctxRDMS.Update(entry);
            ctxRDMS.Save();
```

`ctxRDMS.Update` is:

```
public void Update(Cls entry)
{
       ctx.Entry(entry).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
```

and `ctxRDBMS.Save` is

```
public void Save()
{
   ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The update works fine if i will modify other properties except `firstname`, but as soon as I change it and save it will throw the `OptimisticConcurrencyException` which doesn't make sense because there is no one else editing `firstname` other than me.

Comment: You should read this article: https://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2013/04/08/optimistic-concurrency-in-mongodb-using-net-and-csharp/

Answer (score 0):

I think I have just figured this one out.

If a column is decorated with [concurrencycheck], that column cannot be changed without throwing a concurrency exception (at least I can't change it).

None of the documentation states it so clearly and the examples I see usually choose some column in their example that could well be changed over the life of the data (Last Name, in one case).

The consensus seems to be to use a ROWVERSION column in SQL Server as the only concurrency token in the model.